# Регулярное выражение для поиска слов в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить выражение так, чтобы из строк выбиралось только текстовое предложение.

Например, исходные строки:

```
Dialogue: 0,0:07:10.80,0:07:14.01,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,{\i1}Why doesn't he get it? Leo...{\i0}
Dialogue: 0,0:07:16.06,0:07:17.47,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,We have a problem!
```

На выходе должны получиться строки:

```
Why doesn't he get it? Leo...
We have a problem!
```

Все, до чего я смог додуматься, это получить часть строки до нужного текста:

```
/^([^,]*.){1,9}({.{3}})*/gm
```

Не могу понять, как указать, что данную часть нужно исключить из искомой строки.

Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: Regexp не нужен. Вам нужно разделять строку по запятым и брать все, что после 9-й.

Comment: Что значит не нужен? Мне именно через regexp нужно. Я знаю как это сделать алгоритмом, но мне нужно именно готовое выражение, чтобы передать его в функцию.

Comment: Зачем вам использовать то, что сложно, непонятно, вы не умеете и так далее, если можно использовать более простой метод?

Comment: Если бы была такая возможность, я бы так и сделал. Я бы зря не тратил несколько часов пытаясь решить данную проблему самостоятельно, если бы это можно было сделать проще.

Comment: split() - точно проще.

Comment: Если вы так считаете, приведите пример.

Comment: $str = "Dialogue: 0,0:07:10.80,,,{\i1}Why doesn't he get it? Leo...{\i0}";
echo(substr(split(",", $str, 4)[3], 1)); например.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зависит от формата, но если необходимо сматчить весь текст после девятой запятой, за исключением опциональных `{\i1}` тэгов, можно использовать следующее регулярное выражение:

```
/^(?:[^,]*,){9}(?:{.{3}})?([^{]*)(?:{.{3}})?$/gm
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/pE6aR2/1)